# update database field on submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

when the admin ticks a row or more in the table and clicks on the approve button, that row data (request_id is the primary key) should be updated in the database field is_approved and should change 'pending' to 'approved'
The is_approved field has two enum: pending and approved.
How can i do this?

```
<form action = "admin.php" method = "post"> 
<input type="button" name="accept" value="accept" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />    
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['accept'])) {
    $request_id = $_POST['request_id'];

    foreach($request_id as $is_approved) {
     $query = mysql_query("UPDATE request SET is_approved = 'approved' where is_approved =$request_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: change $request_id in your query with $is_approved

Comment: notice undifined index : request_id

Comment: whats the problem ur getting

Comment: You don't have a form with `request_id` as a post, you form only have `submitted`

Comment: request_id is not being passed in form. It should be an array

Comment: Where do you get `$_POST['request_id']` from? And is it really an array? Most likely, you could drop the loop and use a `WHERE..IN` clause instead, doing it all in one query. Also, if you're just learning PHP, **please** drop the `mysql_` extension and use `mysqli_` or PDO instead!

Comment: request_id is the database field. im trying to use this and get the data of the row of each id

Comment: @taylor what you need to do is to look for a good php tutorial and mysql tutorials, then take it from there

Comment: Start with php here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Change your form as:

```
<form action = "admin.php" method = "post"> 
<input type="button" name="accept" value="accept" />
<input type="text" name="request_id[]" value=1/>
<input type="text" name="request_id[]" value=2/>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />    
</form>
```

The value should be your actual `request_id`

Comment: not sure how by changing this, the database field will change from 'pending' to 'approved'. It's the request id row that im trying to use to change the database row of that request id, and the field of that row to approved

Comment: `foreach($request_id as $is_approved) {
     $query = mysql_query("UPDATE request SET is_approved = 'approved' where is_approved =$request_id");
    }` whey you are using array at PHP?